# asymptotic of a power series

Tags: complex-analysis, power-series

Show that
\begin{equation*}
\sum_{n=0}^{+\infty}x^{n^{2}}
\end{equation*}
is equivalent to
\begin{equation*}
\frac{1}{2}\sqrt{\frac{\pi}{1-x}}
\end{equation*}
as $x\in (0,1)$ approaches $1$.

This comes from a French complex analysis book, and normally the answer should not use any fancy theorems, since so far the authors have only covered Cauchy's integral formula.

Comment: **[Hint](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gaussian_integral):** $~\displaystyle\int_0^\infty a^{t^2}~dt~=~?$

Comment: Oh thanks ! I can't believe I didn't think of that.